# Module not found: Error: Recursion in resolving

Tags: jwt, angular9

While running ng test, in Angular 9+ version, I am getting error.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/__ivy_ngcc__/src/jwt.interceptor.js
Module not found: Error: Recursion in resolving
```

Stack:

I am using below configuration:

[image]